# NAS vs Distributed File Systems

Tags: hdfs, nas, glusterfs, distributed-filesystem, weed-fs

What are the use cases when should we prefer over any distributed file system like HDFS? How to decide which one to use or any other comparable alternative?

Comment: This is off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the traditional NAS as an hardware, I think the decision is quite easy to make. If you want lower latency, just use NAS, since it's locally deployed.
NAS can also be an distributed file system, [Alibaba NAS](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/nas?spm=a3c0i.7911826.6791778070.493.44193870SOxlak). the choice between cloud based NAS and HDFS depends on many aspects. Generally speaking, HDSF's latency is lower than NAS(latency also depends on the cloud service provider. CephFS is faster than aliNAS and EFS.). Cloud based NAS adapted POSIX which is more friendly to user. And HDFS doesn't support random write which NAS supports. But HDFS is more suitable as a storage for big data ecosystem, Spark, HBase, Hive can use it as underlayer storage.